# ckEditor 4 not loading CSS file with custom fonts

Tags: javascript, fonts, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor4.x

I've implemented a custom font for CKEditor and although it is showing in the dropdown list it does not apply to the element. I cannot find the cause of why my CSS file isn't loading which is the cause of not applying the new font.

So, on my configuration **default.js** file I added the below lines of code:

```
config.font_names = 'Belluga Solid/Belluga_Solid;' + config.font_names;

config.contentsCss = "../fonts.css";
```

And then created a new **fonts.css** file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Belluga Solid";
    src: local("Belluga Solid"), url("/MyFonts/Beluga/Belluga_Solid.eot") format("embedded-opentype"); /*non-IE*/
    src: url("/MyFonts//Beluga/Belluga_Solid.ttf") format("truetype"); /*non-IE*/
    src: url("/MyFonts//Beluga/Belluga_Solid.svg") format("svg"); /*non-IE*/
}
```

Looking at the source code, it correctly applies fine:

```
<p><span style="font-family:belluga_solid;">Lorem Ipsum</span></p>
```

It seems pretty straightforward to do. Looking at this tutorial the author got it all right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knkFOuKPsKQ

I implemented the same solution but having a hard time figuring out how to solve the issue.

Comment: Any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the value of the font-family property in the element's styling doesn't match the value defined in the @font-face rule. The @font-face rule defined it as `Belluga Solid`, but your inline style sets the value to `belluga_solid`.

You can try modifying the @font-face rule so that it says this instead:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "belluga_solid";
}
```

That way, they will match and your font should hopefully display correctly.

Comment: that wasn't the issue. I'm still blocked in this mysterious issue.